# Listing of mongodb documents in collection throws error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL 
var url = 'mongodb://user:pwd@lo037234.mlab.com:37234/heroku_plpzj3t5j';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

db.collection('members', function(err, collection) {
  collection.find({}, function(err, cursor) {
    cursor.each(function(err, item) {
      console.log(item.telephoneNumber);

    });

    // our collection has returned, now we can close the database
    db.close();
  });
});
});
```

which I am using to list all telephone numbers in a collection members.

However, the code lists the numbers then shows errors like this

```
Connected correctly to server
0820069005
0920069005ww
0220929975
/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'telephoneNumber' of null
    at /home/obulex/workers/actors/actor.js:14:23
    at handleCallback (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:741:16
    at handleCallback (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:675:5
    at handleCallback (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:172:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:507:3)
    at nextFunction (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:651:7)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:692:3)
    at nextObject (/home/obulex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:672:8)
```

Why am i getting the error at the end of the code?

Comment: Have you checked if it is returning an err instead of an item? Perhaps it will give a clue

Comment: The URI included your username and password in clear text. Strongly recommend changing these as soon as possible. -- What version of the driver are you using?

Comment: @AdamHarrison, it would be better if OP delete the question and create it again without sensible data. SO keeps track of changes in questions and answers.

Comment: The so called sensitive data has been intentionally corrupted and no dictionary attack can rearrange them,so its okay.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code is performing a callback in the find() method.

According to the API, collection.find() returns a Cursor object:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find

Try restructuring your code according to some of the examples shown in the link above, or in the tutorial linked below:
https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/query/#query-for-all-documents-in-a-collection

As Henrique mentioned, you may want to remove this question due to the sensitive information that was contained in the original submission.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL 
var url = 'mongodb://logan:password32@username32.mlab.com:37234/heroku_xpzj3t5j';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

   var cursor = db.collection('members').find( );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         console.log(doc.telephoneNumber);
      } else {
         //callback();
      }
   });

});
```